# popToRootViewControllerAnimated doesn't set the prompt properly

Tags: ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, poptoviewcontroller

I have a simple scenario :
a UINavigationController with several embed UITableViewControllers.

Each UITableViewController has a prompt set, except for the ROOT UITableViewController (no prompt).

And in each UITableViewController, there is a UIBarButtonItem to go back to the ROOT UITableViewController:

```
- (void) backHome {
  [[self navigationController] popToRootViewControllerAnimated: YES];
}
```

It actually goes back to the ROOT UITableViewController, but it keep the prompt from the last UITableViewController, while it suppose to remove it ( knowing that the ROOT UITableViewController doesn't have a prompt).

But when I use and hit several time a custom UIBarButtonItem with the code :

```
- (void) back {
  [[self navigationController] popViewControllerAnimated: YES];
}
```

it remove the prompt as expected.

Why popToRootViewControllerAnimated doesn't remove the prompt ? Especially in iOS 8.x. Because it's working in iOS 7.1.2

I use the latest Base SDK 8.1

Comment: how do you set the 'prompt'?

Comment: For the ROOT UITableViewController, I set prompt to nil:
[[self navigationItem] setPrompt: nil];

Comment: in which method do you call `setPrompt` in root view controller?

Comment: `viewDidLoad` is (usually) called  only once for a `UIViewController`, when it's initialized. So it's not called when you pop to the root view controller. Try to move this code to `viewWillAppear`.

Comment: It's not working either. The thing is, when I push just one UITableViewController on top of the ROOT UITableViewController, it's working, the prompt disappears, but pushing more than one UITableViewController, it's not working anymore...

Answer (score 0):

try calling the property on the stack

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated: YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue and can confirm that it still exists with current Xcode & Simulator. I have a prompt on all View Controllers in the Navigation Controller except for the last one.

Popping to root **without** animation works for me and shows the prompt again, which otherwise wouldn't show.

Comment: Please take a look at [answer] for information on how to and what is an appropriate answer for a question. Comments such as `Me too` are not valid answers and should not be created.